# pointers not working correctly in c?

Tags: c, pointers

Hey so I'm trying to write a code where a person inputs a string, and then inputs a smaller second string. The program is supposed to look for the second string within the first string. I'm stuck with the pointers I'm using. I don't think I'm using them the right way. In the function called search I try to print the values that are supposed to be stored in the pointers in a struct only to have the program crash. I added a comment line to the part I'm having trouble with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct subsequence_struct
{
    char* sequence;  // the larger sequence being searched
    int sizesequence; // size of the array sequence
    char* subseq; // the subsequence we are looking for
    int sizesubseq; // size of the char array subseq
    int* locations; // a pointer to a list of locations where the string in subseq is found in sequence.
    int numlocations; // size of the int array locations
} SUBSEQUENCE;


/* function to create space for the sequence,
 read in the sequence from stdio,
 and return a pointer to the sequence */
char* initseq()
{
    SUBSEQUENCE* seq;

    seq = (SUBSEQUENCE*)malloc(sizeof(SUBSEQUENCE));
    seq->sequence = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    printf("Enter the sequence to be searched: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", seq->sequence);
    seq->sizesequence = strlen(seq->sequence);

    return;
}

//on to read in the subsequence and store in subseq
initsubseq(SUBSEQUENCE *input)
{
    input = (SUBSEQUENCE*)malloc(sizeof(SUBSEQUENCE));
    input->subseq = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    printf("Enter the subsequence to search for: ");
    scanf("%s", input->subseq);
    input->sizesubseq = strlen(input->subseq);

    return;
}

printresults(SUBSEQUENCE* input)
{
    return 0;
}

//This where I'm having problems
search(SUBSEQUENCE* ptrToInput)
{
    printf("This is the sequence: %s\n", ptrToInput->sequence);
    printf("This is the subseq: %s", ptrToInput->subseq);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    SUBSEQUENCE* dna=0;
    dna = (SUBSEQUENCE*)malloc(sizeof(SUBSEQUENCE));
    initseq(dna);
    initsubseq(dna);
    search(dna);
    printresults(dna);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using this code in the function and got garbage printing out in the program:

```
ptrToInput = (SUBSEQUENCE*)malloc(sizeof(SUBSEQUENCE));
ptrToInput->sequence = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
ptrToInput->subseq = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
printf("This is the sequence %s\n", ptrToInput->sequence);
printf("This is the subseq %s", ptrToInput->subseq);
```

Comment: `search(SUBSEQUENCE* ptrToInput)` should be `search(SUBSEQUENCE* input)`, right?

Comment: Most of your functions aren't returning what you say they should be.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this code. For starters, `sizeof(char)` and casting the result of `malloc`, modifying local pointers in functions and discarding the results...

Comment: Perhaps you might address the half-dozen compilation *errors* and equitable number of warnings in the posted code before classifying pointers as the root of evil.

Comment: The code compiles in C++ and doesn't give me errors.

Comment: There are other errors, but this alone could never compile: `initseq(dna);`

Comment: @EdS., That actually compiled for me amazingly, but I do not know why...

Comment: @merlin2011: Well, to be fair, `void f();` declares a function `f` that takes an unspecified number of arguments, whereas `void f(void)` declares a function `f` which takes no arguments.  You should be getting quite a few warnings though. Did you use a C compiler?

Comment: @merlin2011 if you compiled it with C, it would compile. If a C++ compilation doesn't fail on that, you need a new toolset.

Comment: I meant it compiles in Dev-C++, it saved and compiled at a .c program however. And the part where it says input->sequence and input->subsequence is wrong. I was moving stuff around between functions and forgot to fix it before I posted it here.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes, I compiled with C.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I know, I added a bit at the end to ask whether or not he was using a C compiler, though... he really had to be. I don't know why I was using C++ rules at first.

Comment: How did this compile? Some of your functions don't even have return types.

Comment: @noobProgrammer: Pre-C99 implicit int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, there are a variety of issues with the current state of your code. Aside from the various syntax issues (which a C compiler would mostly forgive), the major **functional** issue is that you appear to be declaring, allocating, and then ignoring memory in the local functions.

You can fix this by passing in the pointer that you allocating, and then manipulating it instead of declaring a new one in each `init*` function.

The following code will compile with both `gcc` and `g++`, and output the two user inputs rather than `NULL` or random gibberish.

Note that it represents a bunch of corrections, but **does not search for subsequences**, any more than your original code did.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct subsequence_struct {
    char* sequence;  // the larger sequence being searched
    int sizesequence; // size of the array sequence
    char* subseq; // the subsequence we are looking for
    int sizesubseq; // size of the char array subseq
    int* locations; // a pointer to a list of locations where the string in subseq is found in sequence.
    int numlocations; // size of the int array locations
} SUBSEQUENCE;


// You already allocated in main, no need to allocate again.
void initseq(SUBSEQUENCE* seq)
{   
    seq->sequence = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    printf("Enter the sequence to be searched: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", seq->sequence);
    seq->sizesequence = strlen(seq->sequence);
}

// You already allocated in main, no need to allocate again.
void initsubseq(SUBSEQUENCE *input)
{
    input->subseq = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    printf("Enter the subsequence to search for: ");
    scanf("%s", input->subseq);
    input->sizesubseq = strlen(input->subseq);
    return;
}

// This function currently does not search, but it does print the user's inputs.
void search(SUBSEQUENCE* input)
{
    printf("This is the sequence: %s\n", input->sequence);
    printf("This is the subseq: %s\n", input->subseq);
    return;
}
int main(){
    SUBSEQUENCE* dna=0;
    dna = (SUBSEQUENCE*)malloc(sizeof(SUBSEQUENCE));
    initseq(dna);
    initsubseq(dna);
    search(dna);

    // Free various pieces that were allocated.
    free(dna->sequence);
    free(dna->subseq);
    free(dna);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to get this to work for longer than I would like to admit. I'm aware that it doesn't search. I wanted to make sure that the values were getting stored in the right spot before I started working on the search code. Thanks again!

Comment: @JimboJones, You are welcome. If this answer solved your question, please mark it as the accepted answer when the timer is up.